# Codemagic error Invalid encryption key - encrypted variables work only with builds in the same team they were created with

Tags: java, android, react-native, codemagic

I'm trying to build fresh react-native app with codemagic, but each time I got this error "Invalid encryption key - encrypted variables work only with builds in the same team they were created with"

I have created the keystore using following command
"keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000"

and updated the codemagic.yaml as following
https://github.com/kasunglobe/codeMagicTest/blob/f9abc62ee4d2764e14d716dc51b2193940120eed/codemagic.yaml

please help me to find what I did wrong

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid encryption key - encrypted variables work only with builds in
> the same team they were created with

In my case, I was missing `APPLE_ID` so it was left like `APPLE_ID: Encrypted(...)`
After setting `APPLE_ID` to correct encrypted value error disappeared. Then maybe you are missing setting some variables?

Comment: Thanks Michal, I missed GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS